Override Airflow operator parameters in subclass
I want to enforce max_active_tis_per_dagrun=1 in a subclassed operator.
Tried these approaches:
class BetterKubernetesPodOperator(KubernetesPodOperator):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs) -> None:
        _kwargs = kwargs | { "max_active_tis_per_dagrun": 1 }
        super().__init__(**_kwargs)

class EvenBetterKubernetesPodOperator(KubernetesPodOperator):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.max_active_tis_per_dagrun = 1

However neither seems to work with dynamic task mapping. The only way is to pass it explicitly when instantiating operator:
op = BetterKubernetesPodOperator.partial(task_id="my_task", max_active_tis_per_dagrun=1).expand(...)

It looks like dynamic tasks somehow bypass __init__...? How should I do it?

I assume this is because partial has a constructor with default values set. That's why you are not seeing any effect on the internal value. To be honest, I don't know of any workaround for this, except for passing it explicitly each time. Just remember that everything is Python, and you can wrap the call to the operator as well as the operator itself

Thanks, I see. I wonder if overriding partial somehow could help...?
